# Allocating the total value of a column to specific rows grouped by date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to allocate the total value of a channel to others based on Gross Revenue and Date in Power Query. The data source is from SQL, a query that i made to recover the data from the channel and gross revenue.

In this case I am trying to allocate the total value of channel C to A and B, based on its Gross Revenue on that Month. D does not enter in this calculations

This a dummy table, simplified from the thousands of rows and several columns that I have (In my real table I am going to have several months and not this two, but I believe that is enough for my question):

| Channel | Date | GR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/01/2023 | 5 |
| A | 01/01/2023 | 1 |
| B | 01/01/2023 | 10 |
| B | 01/01/2023 | 4 |
| C | 01/01/2023 | 1 |
| C | 01/01/2023 | 3 |
| D | 01/01/2023 | 5 |
| D | 01/01/2023 | 10 |
| A | 01/02/2023 | 4 |
| A | 01/02/2023 | 2 |
| B | 01/02/2023 | 12 |
| B | 01/02/2023 | 2 |
| C | 01/02/2023 | 1 |
| C | 01/02/2023 | 3 |
| D | 01/02/2023 | 1 |
| D | 01/02/2023 | 2 |

The table from PowerQuery that I expect is as following:

| Channel | Date | GR | GR2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01/01/2023 | 5 | 6 |
| A | 01/01/2023 | 1 | 1,2 |
| B | 01/01/2023 | 10 | 12 |
| B | 01/01/2023 | 4 | 4,8 |
| C | 01/01/2023 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 01/01/2023 | 3 | 0 |
| D | 01/01/2023 | 5 | 0 |
| D | 01/01/2023 | 10 | 0 |
| A | 01/02/2023 | 4 | 4,8 |
| A | 01/02/2023 | 2 | 2,4 |
| B | 01/02/2023 | 12 | 14,4 |
| B | 01/02/2023 | 2 | 2,4 |
| C | 01/02/2023 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 01/02/2023 | 3 | 0 |
| D | 01/02/2023 | 1 | 0 |
| D | 01/02/2023 | 2 | 0 |

What I have right now is this code that I slighty modified from a previous question:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Channel", type text}, {"GR", Int64.Type}, {"GR 2", type number}}),
    #"NotCFiltered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Channel] = "A" or [Channel] = "B" )),
    #"NotCFiltered Rows II" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Channel] = "D")),
#"CFiltered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Channel] = "C")),
Total = List.Sum(#"CFiltered Rows"[GR]),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"NotCFiltered Rows", "GR2", each ( [GR]/ List.Sum(#"NotCFiltered Rows"[GR])) * List.Sum(#"CFiltered Rows"[GR]) + [GR] ,type number) & #"NotCFiltered Rows II" & #"CFiltered Rows"
in  #"Added Custom"
```

However I am not being able to filter by the month - the calculation is doing the total of all the Gross Revenue, for both months

Thanks in advance for your help.

**TL;DR: Trying to allocate the total of the channel value to the other channel based on GR and Date**

**Edit 1: What I am trying to achieve is something dynamic - I can filter by month, but I would have to do each code for each month - I am trying to see if there is another way besides that**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Channel", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"GR", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Month", each Date.Month([Date])),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Month"}, {{"data", each 
    let NotCFilteredRows = Table.SelectRows(_, each ([Channel] ="A" or [Channel] ="B")),
    CFilteredRows = Table.SelectRows(_, each ([Channel] = "C")),
    DFilteredRows = Table.SelectRows(_, each ([Channel] = "D")),
    AddedCustom =  Table.AddColumn(NotCFilteredRows, "GR2", each ( [GR]/ List.Sum(NotCFilteredRows[GR])) * List.Sum(CFilteredRows[GR]) + [GR] ,type number),
    combined =  AddedCustom & CFilteredRows & DFilteredRows 
    in combined
, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Channel", "Date", "GR", "GR2"}, {"Channel", "Date", "GR", "GR2"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Channel", type text}, {"Date", type datetime}, {"GR", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Date"}, {{"All", each _, type table [Channel=nullable text, Date=nullable datetime, GR=nullable number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddColumn( [All], "GR2", (x)=> 
    let a =List.Sum( Table.SelectRows([All], (y)=>  y[Channel] = "A")[GR]),
    b = List.Sum(Table.SelectRows([All], (y)=>  y[Channel] = "B")[GR]),
    c = List.Sum( Table.SelectRows([All], (y)=>  y[Channel] = "C")[GR]),
    d = (x[GR]/(a+b)) 
    in if x[Channel]="A" or x[Channel]="B" then (d * c) + x[GR] else 0
    )),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Date", "All"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", {"Channel", "Date", "GR", "GR2"}, {"Channel", "Date", "GR", "GR2"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

Comment: dang, 4 minutes!

Comment: A bit of healthy competition for you ;)

Comment: maybe I'll learn Vega

Comment: Thank you both for your help (again!)

For my current problem the answer from @horseyride fits best (as I have a lot of channels and a lot of dates) - but both answers work beautifully!

Comment: You should! You can do data manipulation via transforms which would be right up your street.